# Using a existing connection in a Script Component (SSIS)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, ssis

I have am OLEDB Connection configured in the connection managers and I want to use it in a SCRIPT. The script needs to call a stored proc and then create buffer rows. I have added the connection to the connections available to the script and this is my code.

```
Boolean fireagain = true;

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

conn = (SqlConnection)(Connections.Connection
    .AcquireConnection(null) as SqlConnection);


SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

conn.Open();

ComponentMetaData.FireInformation(
           0, "Script", "Connection Open", string.Empty, 0, ref fireagain);

cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "up_FullTextParser_select" ;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Phrase", DbType.String).Value = Row.Keywords;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SpecialTerm", DbType.String).Value = "Exact match";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("StopListId", DbType.Int32).Value = 0;
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

while (rdr.Read())
{
    TermsBuffer.AddRow();

    TermsBuffer.Term = rdr[0].ToString();
}

conn.Close();
```

Anyway, it seems to fail on the AcquireConnection. Am I converting this wrong? Should I be using a different way to using the connections defined outside the script?.

Comment: Please post any and all errors you're getting.

Comment: `conn = (SqlConnection)(Connections.Connection
    .AcquireConnection(null) as SqlConnection);` - This is redundant. With `as`, you are converting the returned object to a `SqlConnection`. You are then casting this `SqlConnection` to the type `SqlConnection`, which it by definition already is, unless it's null, in which case it can't be cast anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot cast an OLEDB connection to SqlConnection object. You must use the OleDbConnection object. See the example - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/08/22/accessing-oledb-connection-managers-in-a-script.aspx

Comment: Also refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867639/connect-to-sql-database-inside-script-task-in-ssis

Comment: @Jabez links to a question about a Script _Task_. A Script Task is not the same as a Script _Component_.

Answer (score 1):

[This MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136018.aspx) implies that you using `AcquireConnection` incorrectly.

Comment: Those cast simply returns null on my computer :(

Comment: The example you link to is for a Script _Task_, not for a Script _Component_. Within a Script Component, the `Dts` object doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a managed connection provider.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using an OLEDB connection, you cannot use `AcquireConnection` but you can extract the connection string and then use it to create an OLEDB connection:

```
string connstr = Dts.Connections["my_OLEDB_connection"].ConnectionString;
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection objConn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connstr);
```

This may not work if the connection string is created via an expression of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

```
    IDTSConnectionManager100 connMgr = this.Connections.ADONetAppStaging ; //this we need to give name in connection manager in script component
    SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
    myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(connMgr.AcquireConnection(null));
    //Read data from table or view to data table
    string query = "Select top 10 * From ##AP_Stagging_Temp_ExportWODuplicates Order by 1,2,3 asc ";
   // string query = "Select  * From ##AP_Stagging_Temp_For_JLL_ExportWODuplicates order by 1,2,3 asc ";
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, myADONETConnection);
   datatable dtExcelData = new datatable();
    adapter.Fill(dtExcelData);
    myADONETConnection.Close();
```