# Connect to SQL database inside Script Task in SSIS

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis, script-task

Inside of a Script Task in SSIS, I need to make a call to an SQL database. I have a connection string that was created when I added the database to the data sources folder, however now I'm not sure how to reference it inside the C# code. I know how to do this in the code behind of an ASP website, however it seems that SSIS should have a more direct method.

EDIT

This line of code actually winds up throwing an exception:

```
sqlConn = (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)cm.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
```

It reads: "Unable to cast COM object of type 'System._ComObject' to class type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConection.'"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you cant use the configurations from a connection manager from inside a script task like:
conectionManager1.exceuteSQLStatment(...)

once you are "inside" the script task you need to access the CM like a variable:

```
ConnectionManager cm;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConn;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqlComm;

cm = Dts.Connections["conectionManager1"];

sqlConn = (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)cm.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
sqlComm = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("your SQL Command", sqlConn);
sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

cm.ReleaseConnection(sqlConn);
```

Comment: If I wanted to get a value (in my case I'm trying to get a DateTime) out of the sqlComm, would I just use something like: DbDataReader reader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader() - and then cycle through the whatever comes out?

Comment: By changing the database connection from OLEDB to ADO.Net, the code listed above worked for me.

Comment: @Tequila. You would have to use Oledb objects to connect using an Oledb connection eg..System.Data.OleDbOleDbConnection and OleDbCommand...

Comment: @Diego - You deserve a gold medal for this post. This saved me tons of time. Btw, where can I get information about these kind of things ? Was this thing mentioned in some MS documentation ?

Comment: @Tequila - That is correct. That is exactly what is needed. Looks like OLEDB will not work here.

Comment: Wbere do you get Dts.Transaction from?  It does not seem to be available in my project @Diego.

Comment: Note this **will not** work with OLEDB, per the Microsoft Docs, and all of this is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/task/connecting-to-data-sources-in-the-script-task

Comment: @MartinMacPherson - trying to cast the rawConnection (after `AcquireConnection`) to OleDbConnection throws an exception. Have you tried that and have it work in this context? Your comment seems wrong.

Comment: I'm connecting to ASE (Adaptive Server Enterprise) using ado.net but going through odbc since the ado.net driver isn't exposed in SSIS connection wizard. One thing I learned was to make sure you use the exact name of the connection (including spaces) or your connection manager won't be found in your script task.

Answer (score 1):

You must check the privider of the connection that your are trying to instantiate.

You can't cast a `OleDb.OleDbConnection` connection as a `SQLClient.SQLConnection`, the parameters are different.