# Modern way connect to SQL Server inside Script Task in SSIS 2012 and later

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

When you search the internet or SO how to [connect to SQL database inside Script Task in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867639/connect-to-sql-database-inside-script-task-in-ssis) you will find .NET v1.1ish code like this:

```
ConnectionManager cm;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConn;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqlComm;

cm = Dts.Connections["ADO.NET.SqlDB"];    
sqlConn = (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)cm.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);

sqlComm = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("your SQL Command", sqlConn);
sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

cm.ReleaseConnection(sqlConn);
```

I am looking for updated code that makes good use of later introduced .NET features.

For a start, how about the code below. Is this the current recommended way to connect to SQL Server inside Script Task in SSIS 2012 and later or do I miss something here?

```
ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections["ADO.NET.SqlDB"];
using (var sqlConn = (SqlConnection)cm.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction))
{
    if (sqlConn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        sqlConn.Open();

    using (var sqlComm = new SqlCommand(
        String.Format("UPDATE myTab SET Processed = 4 where ID = '{0}'",
        idNumber), sqlConn))
    {
        return sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Is the `ReleaseConnection()` still needed?
Is `sqlConn.Open()` really needed in an SSIS context?

---

One year later, and hopefully a little wiser, I settled with code like this:

```
ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections["ADO.NET.SqlServerDB"];
var sqlConn = (SqlConnection)cm.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(
  "INSERT INTO apou_moodle_import(id_num, username, email) VALUES(@IdNum, @Username, @Email)",
  sqlConn))
{
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdNum", newUser.id_num);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", newUser.username);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", newUser.email);

    int rowsAffected = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
cm.ReleaseConnection(sqlConn);
```

So, I keep using ConnectionManager.`ReleaseConnection`, however, SqlConnection.`Open` & `Close` are not needed in an SSIS context. Plus, use Parameters to play safe.

Comment: In that particular code, `sqlConn` would never already be open. But it doesn't hurt. I guess this is a trivial example right? In these examples there is no reason to use a script task, you can just use a SQL Task instead

Comment: Of course, it's just a simple example. Imagine a number of functions that do Selects, Updates, Inputs, etc.

Comment: In my experience this is better implemented in a stored procedure than in a SSIS script task.

Comment: Imagine a package that does REST calls, serializes objects, compress images, and other stuff that is hard to achieve in a stored procedure.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable use for a script task, but again it would probably be better suited in a console app. Can you tell I don't like script tasks? :)

Comment: I see your point but a Script Task has some virtues too, eg. you can use the DTS log, access package variables, easy deployment, etc. Anyways, this not an XY problem question. :)

Comment: I tend to use the OleDB connection as it is the same as the SQL connection manager in the application. Furthermore, I set the connection string from config file to both the CM and to a variable if the package uses a script task. And I use the variable in the script task instead of calling CM. Using the config allows for switching environments (DEV, TEST, PROD) with just a config update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `using` structure allows you to automate disposing variables and handle it better. However, `sqlConn` is not a simple class, it is a **ConnectionManager** instance. When you start using it, you call `AcquireConnection`, when end - call `ReleaseConnection`. The `ReleaseConnection` may perform some housekeeping specific to this Data Source. Depending on **ConnectionManager** implementation, it may check at disposal whether `ReleaseConnection` was called or not and call it.

To my understanding, your code with `using` should be Ok in most cases. Problems may arise when you repeatedly open connections and do not release it - you might run of connection pool etc. I would wrap internals into **try - finally** block to ensure ReleaseConnection execution.